# Что означает эта надпись на PHP и как ее прочитать?

Tags: php

Имеется вот такая строка в PHP-коде:

```
cPAGETYPE=='portal'?define('cPAGEPATH','templates/portal/'.$kernel['settings'] 'template__portal'].'/'):define('cPAGEPATH','templates/admin/'.$kernel['settings'] 'template__admin'].'/');
```

Вопрос: что здесь происходит и как это прочитать? Что означает знак "?" перед первым define и ":" перед вторым define?

Comment: Зачем создавать константу в этом случае? Константа - она и в Африке константа... при любых условиях всегда должна быть самой собой. Самое ужасное - поставлять значения для константы, исходя из каких-то либо условий.

Comment: Ну, если не обращать внимание на тернарный оператор, не все так плохо. Скорее всего это некий конфиг, где предварительное значение константы далее по коду ее же и переопределяет.

Похожие вещи можно встретить в библиотеках Си, когда варианты значений одних деректив определяют значения других.

Comment: >> Самое ужасное - поставлять значения для константы исходя из каких-то либо условий.

Да что вы говорите, хранить ось/рут в глобальной переменной лучше?) Или мб вызывать каждый раз функцию определения?

@KiTE, только некрасивое использование или я что-то еще не вижу? Напр. `define('cPAGEPATH', cPAGETYPE=='portal'?$v1:$v2)`

Comment: Константа - википедия. 
"предварительное значение константы далее по коду ее же и переопределяет"

2- это два !!!! Это константа. 2x2 =4 - ЭТО НЕРЕАЛЬНО ОСПОРИТЬ !!! Это константа и точка тут ! 

И переменная - это то, что может изменить свое значение.
2*x = y - типо того.

Comment: Вы прям пытаетесь доказать, что 2 может быть равнозначным 4-м... в зависимости, например, от погоды.

Comment: @Станислав Комар, в программировании несколько по-другому.

Comment: Я бы предложил в данном случае использовать бытовые флаги и задавать имя ПЕРЕМЕННОЙ исходя из нужного флага!

Т.е. 


define ('FLAG1', 0x100);


define ('FLAG2', 0x200);

if($e & PORTAL1)
   $res |= 123;
if($e & PORTAL2)
   $res |= 456;

Comment: Ок, а из функции, выполненной во вложенном файле, переменную как доставать? через `$GLOBALS`, который можно подменить (напр. в CMS со сторонними модулями и без глобального фасада)?

Comment: В программировании 2 может равняться 4-м  ?:) 
Константа - изменяемое значение ? :) 
0 можно переопределить в true ? 

Что, правда в программировании по другоу ? :)

Comment: @Станислав Комар в крестах (C++) можно =) `#define 5 false` :)

Суть не в этом. Константа в коде ТС не переопределяется. Константа должна определяться один раз, факт. А уж из каких значений она собирается - никого волновать не должно, это не следует из определения константы. В данном случае это дает плюс к безопасности, т.к. никакой код ниже (сторонний модуль, да) не может переопределить критичное значение. И ничего плохого в таком подходе нет, не всегда есть смысл создавать глобальный объект вроде `$APPLICATION`.

Comment: @Станислав Комар, на счет того что переменная не должна влиять на значение константы, ты прав. Но в куске кода из вопроса нет переменных. В условии проверяется значение той же самой константы `cPAGETYPE`. Она же по условию и переопределяется.

Вся тупость этого кода (не считая тернарной операции) в том, что переопределяется заранее созданная константа, а не создается новая.

А условные директивы `#ifdef` и установка значений `#define` по этому условию - это стандартная практика конфигурирования исходников со времен великих и могучих C/C++.

Comment: @KiTE, в коде 2 константы, читаем код внимательнее=) `cPAGETYPE и cPAGEPATH`

PHP падает при попытке переопределения.

Comment: @Sh4dow, точно. Не разглядел.

Comment: Это часть кода метода загрузки шаблона при генерировании страницы (шаблонизатора). В зависимости от параметра cPAGETYPE подключаем либо пользовательский шаблон, либо шаблон админки сайта.

В любом случае спасибо за ответы. Да, тернарный оператор ввел в заблуждение...немного перемудрено получилось.

Comment: Автор наверное все переменные в коде дефайнит))) Чтобы не париться с "$"...

Comment: В некоторых случаях удобно ими пользоваться, особенно при написании ядра CMS-системы...

Answer (score 3):

```
if (cPAGETYPE == 'portal')
 {
  define('cPAGEPATH','templates/portal/'.$kernel['settings'] 'template__portal'].'/');
 }
else
 {
  define('cPAGEPATH','templates/admin/'.$kernel['settings'] 'template__admin'].'/');
 }
```

[Тернарная условная операция](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Тернарная_условная_операция)

[Тернарный условный оператор в PHP](http://php.su/learnphp/operators/?compar)

Answer (score 0):

Аналог классическим способом:

```
if( cPAGETYPE=='portal' ){
    define('cPAGEPATH','templates/portal/'.$kernel['settings']['template__portal'].'/');
}else{
    define('cPAGEPATH','templates/admin/'.$kernel['settings']['template__admin'].'/');
}
```

Автор этого куска кода немного перемудрил, когда воспользовался [тернарным оператором](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F#PHP) не по назначению.