# Выбор переменной при присваивании

Tags: php, переменные, условия

Есть такие переменные

```php
$z1='';
$z2='hell';
```

как присвоить z3 значение по аналогии со следующим кодом?

```php
$z1='';
$z2='hell';
if(!empty($z1))
  $z3=$z1;
else
  $z3=$z2;
```

Comment: В чем смысл аналогии?

Comment: Вас интересовало `$z3 = $z1 ? $z1 : $z2;`? Тогда это дубликат одного из вопросов: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/80718, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/103398, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/351700 и других

Comment: @BOPOH,благодарю то что надо.не знал как сформулировать вопрос для гугла)

Comment: $z3 = $z1 ? : $z2;
Если php свежый

Answer (score 1):

```
$z3 = (empty($z1)) ? $z2 : $z1;
```

Comment: такой тенарный не интересует

Comment: Скобки - зло...